# Rewrite dynamic urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a user.php file that contains code for different pages - account, data and home. They are currently accessed through a dynamic url with GET parameters like so:

```
http://localhost/user.php?page=home
http://localhost/user.php?page=account
http://localhost/user.php?page=data
```

They all work fine and I am happy with how it works. But what I would like is for them to be displayed as `http://localhost/user/<thepagename>/`, preferably with `?page=home` as `http://localhost/user/`.

I have tried a few .htaccess rules from the web but these either completely don't work, or they require me to go through user.php to get to the rewritten urls, which is just as messy and "ugly" as having the parameters in the url (as in `http://localhost/user.php/pagename/`).

I know the rewrite is not necessary in this case but I am working on this as a sort of testing project to get to grips with the practical uses for a variety of functions and practices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/?$ /user.php?page=home [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+?)/?$ /user.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Great, thanks Anubhava. Is there a way of making `/user/` redirect to or load as `?page=home`?